# How to achieve the following

Tags: android, android-layout

How to achive the below image 
1. background yellow.
2. selection image on right top.
3. other image on middle
4. text may be above or below based on need

How to achieve this by button or textview or view

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### `RelativeLayout` will resolve this problem

---

**Code**:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="#000000" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Text" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

**Snapshot**::

[image]

---

### {EDIT}

*You cannot achieve this as a single view*

***Workaround***

- You can achieve this as single view using a background drawable
- Make a background image having both the images in an another image
- Set that final image as a background for a button
- You can even use selectors for the button to give a corner background

Comment: Hi can help me how to achieve by single view. Because already i have implemented except top image by single view that is y asking.

Answer (score 1):

Use `RelativeLayout`. The code will somehow look like this :

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <!-- First image -->
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />        
    <!-- Second image -->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/mySecondImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/mySecondImage" />
</RelativeLayout
```

Comment: Hi can help me how to achieve by single view.

Comment: You can do it with a single view, but it's awfully complicated compared to this. I warmly recommend to use what i said : the API already includes classes that enable to do layout, why re-inventing them ?